# Fluentbit forward retry limit and HA

Tags: fluentd, fluent-bit

I want have a setup of multiple fluentbit that forward to a single fluentd (or two).

The [HA architecture of fluentd](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/high-availability) is clear, but is it applicable with fluentbit=>fluentd architecture?

Fluentd have file based buffering with retries that can configured to days or weeks in case that the target inresponssive for a long timeto avoid loosing records. Can we have file based buffering and retry for such a long time with fluentbit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, the FluentBit cannot be set up in HA mode exactly like FluentD. As [mentioned here](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/565)

> the only HA mode supported is in-memory buffering, meaning: if the
>   logs cannot be shipped to the destination there is a retry logic in
>   place.
>
> If you refer to HA where having primary and secondary destinations as
>   well with balancing support that feature has not been implemented yet.

From [another bug description](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/905) it seems like if you configure two IP addresses behind a hostname which is used in the fluentbit configuration, you might be able to achieve HA. Based on your context, YMMV